# How can I run a function with players not in spectator mode in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am making a last team standing game, and part of it is teaming up during the game. I think that the best way is to test for when there only one team with the players in survival mode. What commands should I use and is there any better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the target selector `@a[gamemode=survival,team=blue]` to target all players that are in survival mode and are on team blue.

```
/kill @a[gamemode=survival,team=blue]
```

This command would kill all players on team blue, who are not in survival mode

[Some more information on target selectors](https://www.digminecraft.com/getting_started/target_selectors.php)

[How to use teams in 1.13 or newer](https://www.digminecraft.com/game_commands/team_command.php)

The best solution for you may vary, depending on your exact needs, or what other features you may want to include.

Comment: Shouldn't it be gamemode=survival since they want players in survival?

Comment: You are correct, though the question itself said "not in spectator mode"

I will edit the answer, thank you

Comment: Oh yeah, the question header and body are different and I guess we looked different parts.